# Unable to find the template docker-compose.vs.debug.yml

Tags: .net, visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm sorry to bother you,
I am using Visual Studio with which I have generated Docker images and docker-compose files for my ASP.NET solution.

However, when I try to run the debug, the following error is returned to me:

```
8>------ Build started: Project: docker-compose, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
8>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(318,5): error CTC1030: Unable to find the template docker-compose.vs.debug.yml.

8>Done building project "docker-compose.dcproj" -- FAILED.
```

Since Visual Studio normally generates all these files for docker-compose automatically, I don't understand that this is missing. How can I generate it? (I already tried to regenerate the docker-compose project)

I have read the Microsoft documentations explaining the interest of the file but it is not said anywhere how to create it or where to place it.

Thanks for your help,

Alex

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I'm having this issue after I updated Visual Studio

Comment: I encountered the same problem and found the mistake. I realized that I had mistakenly selected the output type of my console application as 'Windows application', which disrupted my Docker settings for the Linux container. When I corrected the application settings back to 'console application', the problem was resolved. Maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose.vs.debug.yml should be placed in the same folder where you have your docker-compose.yml file. You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties?view=vs-2019)

You might also want to look at the section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties?view=vs-2019#docker-compose-file-labels) to see how you can structure the file and the entry point to attach the debugger.

Comment: But isn't this file supposed to be automatically generated by visual studio ?

Like the docker-compose.dcproj ect.. ?